# SQLite, Linq, Foreach: how to optimize performances?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sqlite, foreach

I've developed an **UWP app** where I use a **SQLite** database to store datas that are synced.

Among these data, there a lot of tables that contain **translated data**. For example, for various cases, we have:

- a "**businness**" table, which contains the id that is really used in the database
- a "**translation**" table, which contains transaltion for the business table

The models of the "**business**" tables are defined like this:

```
public class Failure_Type : BasePoco
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int failure_id { get; set; }

    public int? function_type_id { get; set; }

    public int? component_category_id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200), NotNull]
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? disable_date { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string _descriptionTr { get; set; }
}
```

The field "***description***" stores the english/default description, and the "***_descriptionTr***" field will store the translated description.

The models of the "**translation**" tables are defined like this:

```
public class Failure_Type_Translation : BasePoco
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public int failure_type_translation_id { get; set; }

    public int? failure_type_id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string language { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200), NotNull]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

The field "***failure_type_id***" is related to the business table, the other fields store the language code and the related translation.

So, after syncing datas in the SQLite database, I refresh the "translated" datas in the app and this can take a long moment. The load of the the 2 tables from the SQLite is very quickly, but the update of the "***_descriptionTr***" field can be very slow:

```
var failureType = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().GetAll<Failure_Type>();
var failureTypeTranslations = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>().GetAll<Failure_Type_Translation>();
FailureType = new ObservableCollection<Failure_Type>();
foreach (var ft in failureType)
{
    var ftt = failureTypeTranslations.FirstOrDefault(i => i.failure_type_id == ft.failure_id && i.language.ToLower().Equals(lang));
    if (ftt != null)
        ft._descriptionTr = ftt.description;
    else
        ft._descriptionTr = ft.description;
    FailureType.Add(ft);
}
```

***Is there a better way for doing this?
How could I optimize it?***

Edit :

- the "business" table contains 550 rows
- the "translation" table contains 3500 rows
- the duration of the loop is nearly 1 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Create the observable collection at once ...

   ```
   FailureType = new ObservableCollection<Failure_Type>(failureType);
   ```

   ... so the individual additions don't fire notifications. Now use `FailureType` in the loop.
2. Instead of fetching all translations, filter them by `lang`:

   ```
   var failureTypeTranslations = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepository>()
       .GetAll<Failure_Type_Translation>()
       .Where(l => i.language == lang);
   ```
3. Create a dictionary for lookup of known translations:

   ```
   var dict = failureTypeTranslations.ToDictionary(ftt => ftt.failure_id);
   foreach (var ft in FailureType)
   {
        Failure_Type_Translation ftt;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(ft.failure_id, out ftt)
            ft._descriptionTr = ftt.description;
        else
            ft._descriptionTr = ft.description;
   }
   ```

I think that esp. the part `failureTypeTranslations.FirstOrDefault` kills performance. The query is executed for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thank you @Get Arnold, by combining your suggestions, I'm passing from 1 minute to an half second.